# How to disable user registration in Joomla 3.x

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

In Older versions this option was at Global Configuration section.
At joomla 3.x seems that this option has been moved.

I want only my existing users to be able to login.

Has anyone any idea where this option is available? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Log into your Joomla 3.0 admin dashboard
2. In the top menu, click Users and then click User Manager
3. In the tabs toward the top of the page, click the Options tab
4. Under the Component tab, find the following setting:

   Allow User Registration

   ```
   If set to Yes, new Users allowed to self-register.
   ```

To disable user registration, set Allow User Registration to No, and then click the Save button in the top left of the page.

After disabling the registration option, you will notice that the Create an account link within your Login Form will no longer show, as users can no longer create an account on their own.

[Reference](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/joomla-3/registered-users/disabling-user-registration)

Answer (score 3):

It's very simple ,Follow the steps below:
a)select System --> Global Configuration -->Users manager.
b)Under the component tab you will see the 1st option as Allow user registration.

Please refer the screenshot below.
[image]